# Error 403 Update HTML Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm writing my first project in Laravel. I have an update form that has a textarea and submit button. The form and the controller work well when I use it on my local server and updates the values ​​to the database. In Production when I add HTML content it shows me a 403 error, POST. However if I write regular plain text, it does the update without problem. I do not understand why this error is happening. Can you help?

## Form

```
{{ Form::model($partido, array('route' => array('dashboard.partidos.update', $partido->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'accept-charset'=>'UTF-8' )) }}

    {{ Form::hidden('accion', 'add-resumen') }}
    {{ Form::hidden('id', $partido->id) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('resumen', $partido->resumen,['id'=>'resumen']) }}

    <div class="form-group">
      <div id="summernote">{{ $partido->resumen }}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::submit('Guardar Resumen', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

## Controller

```
$rules = array(
    'id'         => 'required',
    'resumen'    => 'required'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// process the login
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('dashboard/partidos/'.$id)
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
} else {
    $resumenPartido = $partido::find($id);
    $resumenPartido->resumen = Input::get('resumen');
    $resumenPartido->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Resumen guardado satisfactoriamente');
    return Redirect::to('dashboard/partidos/'.$id)->with('query',$query);
}
```

If you could help me 
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of server are you using? And are you hosting on windows or linux?

Comment: Whats the error message? if you dont get one set "debug" to true in config/app.php